# Узнать тип данных, содержащихся в контейнере в шаблонной функции

Tags: c++

Имеется шаблонная функция, принимающая stl контейнер(например вектор)

```
template<typename T>
createBuffer(T& _array, VkBufferUsageFlags _usage, uint32_t _property)
```

Содержимое её не важно, однако знать тип данных который содержится очень нужно. Можно ли как-нибудь с помощью шаблона выяснить это? Ну или другим каким-либо способом

Answer (score 0):

Для всех стандартных контейнеров определен `typedef value_type`. Использование:

```
template<typename T>
createBuffer(T& _array, ...) {
    for( typename T::value_type x : _array )
         ...
```

Однако, этот механизм не работает для стандартны массивов `int array[10]`.

Более универсальный способ `decltype`:

```
template<typename T>
createBuffer(T& _array, ...) {
    typedef decltype( * std::begin(_array) ) value_type;
    for( value_type x : _array )
         ...
```

Ну и следует помнить, что часто можно заменить `decltype` на `auto`, и это улучьшит читаемость:

```
template<typename T>
createBuffer(T& _array, ...) {
    for( auto x : _array )
           ...
    auto x0=_array[0]; ...
```

Comment: Не совсем то, что мне нужно. Мне необходимо привести к типу содержащегося в контейнере элемента

Comment: Приводите `return static_cast<T>(expression);`

Comment: Или так `_array = *(T*)pointer`

Comment: @СергейТерпеливый у вас в руках есть typedef нужного типа (value_type).  Почему не получается привести к нему?